# How do you create a linear regression formula from the results of a summary in R?

Tags: r, regression, anova, linear

Say you have:

```
data.lm
summary(data.lm)
```

It prints out:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  510.1451   159.9921   2.510   0.0075 **
data$whatever  -0.7644     0.4551  -2.352   0.0359 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 15.32 on 16 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.421, Adjusted R-squared:  0.429 
F-statistic: 6.13 on 1 and 16 DF,  p-value: 0.0491
```

How exactly do I extract the formula from that?

> y = a + bx

a = the intercept, so 510.1451?

b = the slope, so it would be the "Estimate" on data$whatever: -0.7644 ?

What is "x"?

I'm not too sure how to interpret and transform into a formula.

Comment: See [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret+regression+coefficient+formula+is%3Aanswer+score%3A1)

Comment: *You* wrote the formula "$y=bx,$" not the software, so what do *you* mean by "x"??

Comment: The linear regression formula is: "y = a + bx", right?

Now I'm trying to find the value of "a" and "b" from the summary printed in R.

Comment: `x` and` `y` are meaninglessly abstract.  In this case the linear regression formula is `Response = Intercept + coefficient TIMES data$whatever`.  I'm sure you can match that to the `lm` output to figure out what the values of `Intercept` and `coefficient` are.

Answer (score 1):

(edited)
I see you have this model
$$ Y = \alpha + \beta X+ u$$
and doing a linear regression you have those numbers, where $\hat{\alpha} = 510.1451$ and $\hat{\beta} = -0.7644$. So your predicted model is
$$
\hat{Y} = \hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}X
$$
This is
$$
\hat{Y} = 510.1451 + −0.7644 X
$$

X is the regressor, i.e., the variable that explains Y.

Comment: What I mean is that based on the numbers I see from the summary(lm), how do I build the function from that? What numbers represent which variable in the formula?

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!

Answer (score 0):

The "Estimate" column are just that - estimates of the parameters. To run the regression I'm assuming you did something like:

```
data.lm <- lm(Y ~ data$whatever, data=data)
```

This means the model you are estimating is
$$
y = \alpha + \beta \ x_{data$whatever} + \epsilon
$$
so that $\hat{\alpha} = 510.1451$ is the intercept, $\hat{\beta} = -0.7644$ is the estimated coefficient on $x_{data$whatever}$. The other columns are standard errors of the estimates, t values, and p values.

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.